# How do I set a peer dependency optional?

Tags: typescript, npm, winston

I'm developing a module A. The user can, optionally, inject a Winston logger to my module, therefore `winston` is its peer dependency.

Whenever I install my module A in another module where I don't want to log stuff (therefore I don't include Winston) and try to `tsc` it, Typescript yells:

> Cannot find module 'winston' or its corresponding type declarations.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since NPM v7.x, you can use the `peerDependenciesMeta` package.json config, which allows exactly [that option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#peerdependenciesmeta).

For example, in your "Module A" `package.json`:

```json
"peerDependencies": { 
  "winston": "> 1.0.0 <= 1.2.10",
  "foo": "~2.3.0"
},
"peerDependenciesMeta": {
  "winston": {
    "optional": true
  }
}
```

In this case, when installing Module A as a dependency of another project, it will allow installing `winston` dependency version in the semver range specified `> 1.0.0 <= 1.2.10`, but if it's not present at all, you won't get errors, so it will be allowed as well.

Note that following this example, `foo` dependency would be still required because it's not marked as `optional`.

Extra tip: you can check and test ranges on available NPM packages using this utility https://semver.npmjs.com/, it helped me as well.

<sub>PS. this is my first answer on SO! :)</sub>

Answer (score 14):

Just a small addition to @tmilar's answer.
I'm using the same way to add optional dependancy (and also winston :))
the example is for npm@7 which supports `peerDependenciesMeta`

```
"peerDependencies": { 
  "winston": "~3.3.0"
},
"peerDependenciesMeta": {
  "winston": {
    "optional": true
  }
}
```

for optional dependencies you should expect exceptions on require and check package versions

```
let winston;
let winstonVersion;
try {
  winston = require('winston')
  winstonVersion = require('winston/package.json').version
} catch (er) {
  winston = null
}

if (isUnsupportedVersion(winstonVersion) ) {
  winston = null
}

// .. then later in your program ..

if (winston) {
  winston.doSomething()
}
```

Comment: What is `isUnsupportedVersion` in this example, a npm package?